# How to test Ember.Router

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-router

I would like to test my router which for the sake of simplicity looks as follows:

```
// app.router.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('sessions', function() {
    this.route('login');
    this.route('logout');
  });
  this.route('profile');
});

export default Router;
```

Is it possible to unit-test it? 
I tried using acceptance tests but I was not successful:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { test } from 'qunit';

import moduleForAcceptance from 'transformed-admin/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance';

import startApp from 'transformed-admin/tests/helpers/start-app';

moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | configuration', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    this.application = startApp();
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(this.application, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('should map routes correctly', function(assert) {   
  visit('/');

  const app = this.application;

  andThen(function() {
    app.Router.detect("profile"); // false
    app.Router.detect("Profile"); // false

    const a = app.Router.extend({});
    a.detect("profile"); // false
    a.detect("Profile"); // false
  });
});
```

What are the best practices here? Do you test `Router.map()` at all? Or do you rely on testing of concrete routes as a guarantee that the `Router.map()` is written correctly?

Comment: Acceptance tests that check the [currentUrl](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Test.html#method_currentURL) and the [currentPath](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Test.html#method_currentPath) should be more than enough

Comment: Thank you  @Kitler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want to do. You could write [acceptance tests](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/testing/acceptance/) for each route if you want to make sure that they are visible:

```
import { test } from 'qunit';
import moduleForAcceptance from 'people/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance';

moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | login');

test('visiting /', function(assert) {
  visit('/');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/index');
    assert.equal(currentPath(), 'index');
  });
});

test('visiting /profile', function(assert) {
  visit('/profile');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/profile');
    assert.equal(currentPath(), 'profile');
  });
});
```

You could also write [unit tests for your routes](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/testing/testing-routes/).

You should not test Ember.js internals. Ember.Router [is covered by tests](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/tests/system/router_test.js). You should test your application specific logic (eg. handling a specific action in a route by unit test) and behavior (eq. a specific route exists by acceptance test).

Comment: My target was to test: `Router.map()` function.

Comment: @Pavol I updated my answer to clear out, that you should not test framework internals like `Router.map()` but your implementation.

Comment: Thank you, @jelhan. It was clear to me from your answer because my question already included this fact:
"or do you rely on testing of concrete routes ...".
Now I know testing own implementation is enough ;-)